# QTableView with a QSortFilterProxyModel seted on, based on a QSqlQueryModel doesn't update when the data in the database change

Tags: qt, qt5, qtableview, qsortfilterproxymodel, qsqlquerymodel

I have a complex software that has several tables and forms.
I need to join some tables in a QSqlQueryModel and show the result into a QTableView
I use a QSortFilterProxyModel to have the ability to search in the QTableView that contain the result
When I create the QTableView and set the models, everything is OK, but when in another part of the software the database changes I can't see the data changes in the QTableView.

This is a snippet code:

```
void form1::setModels()
{
    queryModel = new QSqlQueryModel();
    queryModel->setQuery("SELECT * FROM table1");
    proxyModel = new QSortFilterProxyModel(queryModel);
    proxyModel->setSourceModel(queryModel);
    ui->tableView->setModel(proxyModel);
}
```

This method is called when I create form1 and it's placed below the database connection and open() call

Before I call form1 with exec I try to do a: (form1 contains the QTableView mentioned)

```
queryModel->query().exec()
```

In order to update the query but nothing happens until I close the program and run again.

Is like something in the middle of the model doesn't update properly

If I call setModels() before the form exec method (not only in the constructor of the form), the QTableView show the change correctly but I think that is not the correct way to do an update, I already have the models, and the tableview, I think that I only need to update the query and refresh the QTableView and the QSortFilterProxyModel, but I don't find the way to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> but when in another part of the software the database changes I can't see the data changes in the QTableView.

You need to update the model, then the view will be notified of any changes done. When you change the table `table1`, you do a reset on this model(reset the model, then query the database).

Comment: Thank you asitdhal, you have open my eyes!
I just only needed to setQuery again and the model resets itself

void QSqlQueryModel::setQuery(const QSqlQuery & query)
Resets the model and sets the data provider to be the given query. Note that the query must be active and must not be isForwardOnly().